# How to get data into a database using PHP and android studio (server 00webhost)?

Tags: java, php, android-studio, database-connection, registration

I've created a database using 000webhost, and uploaded my php files to there server. Using android studio, I'm attempting to create a user register page. I click to go to the register page, type in all the information, hit the submit button and it takes me back to the login page as it should do however, the information was not sent to my database. I'm not receiving and error message so I don't know where to begin. Here is a look at the code from my java classes and the php file as well as a snippet of the manifest file.

**The register request java class**

```
package amp.riot;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL ="https://upbeat.000webhostapp.com/register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password,Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super (Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("age", age + "");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParams(){
        return params;
    }

}
```

The register page java class

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etAge= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    final EditText etName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            final String name=etName.getText().toString();
            final String username=etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password=etPassword.getText().toString();
            final int age= Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

            final Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                            Register.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });

}
```

}

**The manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="amp.riot">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Register PHP File

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id202020_sierra", "05alop59", "id202020_plank");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user(name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Comment: You said you receive an error message, we need it.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say there was no error message which is why I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try `StringRequest` instead of using `Response.Listener<String>`

```
StringRequest strreq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        params.put("id",id);
        params.put("name",editText_name.getText().toString());
        params.put("pass",editText_pass.getText().toString());
        return params;
    }
};
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strreq);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a minor mistake in your php file. 
Change,

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

To,

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
```

Here, s means String, i means Integer. I believe username is String and age is int. Thank You.